# Boto: Calling ELBConnection returns ELBConnection with ec2 endpoint, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-elb

Boto: Calling ELBConnection returns ELBConnection with ec2 endpoint, why?

```
aws_config={ 'region': RegionInfo:us-east-1, 'aws_access_key_id': REALKEY, 'aws_secret_access_key': REALSECRET}
import boto
print boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region(**aws_config)

output: ELBConnection:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

what it should return:

```
ELBConnection:elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

using boto 2.38
This is of course a small excerpt of a larger piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error in your snippet is because of the way you refer region which should be region_name

This with boto 2.38 works as expected

```
>>> import boto
>>> import boto.ec2.elb
>>> aws_config={ 'aws_access_key_id': 'REALKEY', 'aws_secret_access_key': 'REALSECRET', 'region_name': 'eu-west-1' }
>>> print boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region(**aws_config)
```

OUTPUT

```
ELBConnection:elasticloadbalancing.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: I updated the question with missing info, my mistake

Comment: @GilZellner The error you are getting is because in your code you have aws_config={ 'region': RegionInfo:us-east-1,  this should be aws_config={ 'region_name': 'us-east-1',

Answer (score -1):

I'm not seeing that behavior:

```
In [1]: import boto.ec2.elb

In [2]: boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
Out[2]: ELBConnection:elasticloadbalancing.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Here's my version info:

```
In [3]: boto.__version__
Out[3]: '2.38.0'
```